# rails send_data does not send anything when using POST to send Excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rest, axlsx

When I call `send_data` at the end of a controller method to export an Excel file (using Axlsx), nothing happens IF the controller method was called using a POST. If the same controller method was called using a GET, `send_data` works perfectly fine. In both scenarios, the Excel file is slightly different (the POST sends data that determines how the data is displayed in Excel), but I have verified that `excel_file` is set up correctly when using POST. **When calling the POST endpoint externally using Postman, the correct Excel file is downloaded. However, when clicking on the link in the browser that makes this POST request, `send_data` seems to do nothing.** The controller method has two lines of code:

```
excel_file = excel_util.export(params[:myPostParams]
send_data(excel_file.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: "MyExcelWorksheet.xlsx")
```

More information about my POST call:

I am calling the POST from an element on my view using JQuery ($.post method). Like I mentioned above, this seems to work perfectly fine because the POST call goes through passing the correct info in its body as `excel_file` is built correctly.

Examining the Network in chrome's Developer Tools, using POST creates an 'export' action and a 'results' action. `export` is the name of the controller method that handles the POST and GET. Here is the info (only included relevant info, the host/origin/referrer links are all fine).

'export' info:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/<myappname>/export
Request Method: POST

Response Headers:
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="MyExcelWorksheet.xlsx"
Content-Length:7648
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/xlsx
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Miniprofiler-Ids:["i6c3..."]


Request Headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1803
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
<the data I send in the body of my POST>
```

'results' info:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/mini-profiler-resources/results
Request Method: POST

Response Headers:
Content-Type:application/json

Request Headers:
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:64
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
id: <i6c3... < same as the X-Miniprofiler-Id shown above >
popup: 1
```

Is there an issue with rails letting POST requests respond with attachment downloads in the browser? This works when calling API externally, but not when using it in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post/23797348#23797348

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge that would completely explain why the API call works externally but not when used with the browser. Is there any way to make Ajax/browser correctly accept what `send_data` is sending and create a download of it? Or am I forced to use the solution you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed an issue with making a POST call with Ajax, not necessarily an issue with `send_data`. Here is a great workaround for making a POST call in Javascript and handling the call in Rails:

https://gist.github.com/DavidMah/3533415

This worked for me, and I hope this awesome link gets more visibility.